Confirmation that 0-inflated poisson model is specified correctly in jagsUI package
I have data representing counts of roads within a given cell of a raster (value) and I want to examine how it responds to a fixed effect of year (scaled, year_sc) and two random effects of cell ID and grid cell ID (raster and grid). I have worked in rjags before but have switched over to jagsUI for better collaboration with co-workers. I want to make sure that the model I have written is correctly specified. I know my data is 0-inflated so I am trying to specify a 0-inflated poisson distribution here.
model {
    for (i in 1:N) {
    
      # Logit model for certain 0s
      mu[i] <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * year_sc[i] + rasterRE[raster[i]] + gridRE[grid[i]])
      
      # Bernouli distribution, determines if i is 0-inflated or not
      zi[i] ~ dbern(z)
      
      # Inflation model
      value[i] ~ dpois(mu[i] * (1 - zi[i]))

    }
  
    # Priors
    beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    
    for (j in 1:nCells) {
      rasterRE[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau_rast)
    }
    
    for (k in 1:nTiles) {
      gridRE[k] ~ dnorm(0, tau_grid)
    }
    
    tau_rast ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
    tau_grid ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
    
    z ~ dbeta(1, 1)  # Prior for zero-inflation parameter
}

I would really appreciate any help fixing this if this seems incorrect or any confirmation that this is correct!
